# Can I Use $table->uuidMorphs('role') in Laravel for Polymorphic Relationships with Mixed UUID and Integer IDs

Tags: laravel, eloquent, uuid, laravel-10, polymorphic-relationship

I'm currently developing a Laravel application that includes a Users table with a polymorphic relationship to several other models (Teacher, Admin, Student, Manager). Some of these related models use UUIDs as their primary keys, while others use traditional integer IDs. I need to establish a polymorphic relationship from the Users table to these models but am concerned about the potential complications due to the mixed use of UUIDs and integer IDs.

Here's the migration for my Users table:

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary()->default(DB::raw('(UUID())'));
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('mobile', '11');
        $table->string('user_name')->unique()->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->json('avatar')->nullable();
      
        $table->uuidMorphs('role');
        $table->unique(['role_id', 'role_type'], 'role_unique');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('email')->unique()->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    });
}
```

I used $table->uuidMorphs('role') to create the polymorphic relation columns, intending to link users to their roles, which could be any of the mentioned models. My concerns are:

1. Since role_id is designed to store UUIDs and some related models use integer IDs, will this cause data type mismatches or other relational integrity issues?
2. Is there an alternative approach to defining this polymorphic relationship in the migration to accommodate both UUIDs and integer IDs seamlessly?
3. What are the best practices for managing such a scenario where the related models have mixed primary key types?

## Questions:

1. Can I use $table->uuidMorphs('role') effectively in this situation without running into issues with models that use integer IDs?
2. If using $table->uuidMorphs('role') is not advisable here, what is the recommended way to set up a polymorphic relationship in Laravel when dealing with mixed ID types?
3. Are there any examples or patterns in Laravel that cater to polymorphic relationships across models with both UUIDs and integer primary key types?

- **Testing in Development Environment: In my development environment, I've conducted tests using $table->uuidMorphs('role') to set up the polymorphic relationship, even with the mixed ID types. Surprisingly, I haven't encountered any errors or issues so far. Relationships seem to be resolving correctly, and the application behaves as expected. However, I remain concerned about whether this approach is sustainable and reliable in the long term, especially as the application scales and the data volume increases. My testing covered basic CRUD operations and queries involving the polymorphic relationships, but I haven't yet tested more complex scenarios or performance under load.**
- Laravel version: 10.x

I would greatly appreciate any advice, insights, or examples from the community on how to navigate this challenge. Thank you in advance!